# Fontawesome 5 with VuetifyJs 1.0.0

Tags: font-awesome, vuetify.js

I want to use Fontawesome 5 Icons with VuetifyJs. Is that possible? which npm package for fontawesome should I use? because no one worked for me.
It is really confusing for me as an inexperienced VuetifyJs developer to use it, with the lack of any clear steps in the documentation of VuetifyJs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons#example-font-awesome):

> Font Awesome is also supported. Simply use the **fa- prefixed** icon name.
> **Please note that you still need to include the Font Awesome icons in
> your project**.

[Release notes](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v1.0.0):

> Things we added
>
> v-icon now supports FontAwesome 5

You probably just need to include it in your `index.html` inside `<head>` or so

`<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Then use like `<v-icon>fa-search</v-icon>`

Comment: I didn't try that `<link>` tag way. But `fa-search` is for version 4. For version 5 `fba` or similar prefix is required. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @NafaaBoutefer Well that was an example from docs, which is working. Try as instructed and it should work, or if not working, explain what you've tried (or perhaps reproduce with an example) and what were the results so we can resolve it.

Comment: Important thing here is the "fa-" prefix.

Comment: Hi Traxo - got here from a possible duplicate flag on my question. This is semi-useful, but  I'm using the Vue ready Font Awesome 5.2.0 with Vuetify but I'm not including the fontawesome css in html. I'd rather do it on a lightweight icon by icon basis, so my solution from the question should still be useful.

Comment: @MichealJRoberts I have not tried your proposed solution yet. However, thank you for contributing here on this question. I flagged your new question because it seemed like a duplicate of this one to me, so I believe it's much better if you can improve on current answers to post them here, because this question is more popular, and thus more people will probably see your answer here.

Comment: @Traxo Sure, makes sense, happy for it to be flagged - DRY. :) I have added my solution to this question below. Hopefully it helps someone and keeps this issue contained to this question. Strange how this didn't appear on my initial searches...

Answer (score 3):

To bring across my `Vue` specific answer, to get Font Awesome 5 working with `Vuetify.js` I needed the following setup in `main.js`:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faCode } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faCode)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
```

Then I use the imported icon on the template level:

```
<v-btn fab dark small color="black" v-on:click="addCodeBlock">
   <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'code']"/> // <-- This replaces <v-icon>fa-code</v-icon> 
</v-btn>
```

Comment: And what about icons which are used by Vuetify itself? Also is there no way to get v-icon to support svg icons?

Answer (score 1):

## Install

```
yarn add --dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
// or
npm i --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

## Import

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'fa'
})
```

## Use

```
<v-icon>fas fa-lock</v-icon>
```

Comment: Leads to error `Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| .fa,
| .fas,
| .far,
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:36005)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.scope (bundle.js:11814)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at bundle.js:63
    at bundle.js:66`

Comment: Hmm. I am getting: https://k2platform.app/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.woff2?64b3e814a66c2719b15abf8f7998bd73 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) the above.