# FontAwesome with Vuetify - How to include Font Awesome icons within the v-icon component

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, vuetify.js

Hopefully someone will know where I have gone wrong here - I'm trying to implement the Font Awesome package with Vuetify. Font Awesome is all imported and ready to go (setup is indentical to projects which I have Font Awesome successfully integrated):

My bare basics `main.js` file:

```
import '@babel/polyfill'
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'
import './registerServiceWorker'

import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faCode } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faCode)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

And within a component I am referencing an icon as follows:

My `Component.vue`:

```
<template>
    ...
    <v-btn>
        <v-icon>fas fa-code</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    ...
</template>
```

^ Where I have left out superfluous code*.

So, my question is - how do we integrate Font Awesome within Vuetify's v-icon component?

For reference, I’m using what is outlined here:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons

Which is identical to what I have prescribed above, but sadly my icon does not display...

***Update***: I specifically want a solution which doesn't include adding the rather heavy Font Awesome `all.css` file (`<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">`) - instead importing on an icon by icon need. (the overall weight of the minified all.css file is 52kb in `v.5.2.0`.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the `<font-awesome-icon>` component?

Comment: Hi Phil - just using the Vuetify guidelines/docs on icons - says you can use it as I have specified...that was my original thought of maybe using a slot such that it inherits all the stylings of the Vuetify element...but seems redundant if Vuetify specifies it can be done this way.

Comment: Looking at the [example code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetifyjs.com/blob/master/src/examples/icons/fontAwesome.vue), they're just including the FontAwesome CSS in their app. The code you have above is using the FontAwesome + Vue integration

Comment: I see - using the normal vue-fontawesome integration works fine (see my answer below). Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fontawesome 5 with VuetifyJs 1.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783624/fontawesome-5-with-vuetifyjs-1-0-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so using the above commenter's suggestion, I have managed to get it working by using the standard `vue-font-awesome` method of including font awesome icon components, swopping `<v-icon>` out for  such that what I used in my question:

```
<v-btn>
   <v-icon>fas fa-code</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

...becomes:

```
<v-btn fab dark small color="black" v-on:click="addCodeBlock">
   <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'code']"/>
</v-btn>
```

Comment: Anyone know how to do this for the append/prepend icon props?

Comment: @AndrewHarvey You can use slots (e.g. <font-awesome-icon slot="prepend" ... >

Comment: How I can use the social icons? It works well with fa-code but not with fas facebook-f / facebook-f / fab facebook-f.

Answer (score 23):

#### You can use [tree shaking](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#tree-shaking-alternative).

Since you are looking for an option to avoid loading all icons into vue/vuetify, I suggest that you utilize the tree shaking method and add each icon you want to use, manually. This can be a bit tedious but adding in icons on demand will be beneficial in the long term - as webpack will just bundle up the ones you specify.

> **Please note**:
>
> *In this tutorial, I assume that the reader has the Pro package. If you only want to use the free ones just remove anything resembling pro from the mix*

Below you can see my preferred way of doing this with vuetify and using SVGs with v-icon and v-text/v-html:

**First we have to install the icons:**

*(open up your terminal/command-prompt inside your project and install)*

```js
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core // this is the svg core, it is needed.
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome // Vue integration *
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons // Branding icons
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons // only for FA5 free **
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons // only for FA5 free **
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons // Pro icons regular type
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons // Pro icons light type
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons // Pro icons solid type
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons // Pro icons duotone type ***
```

1. *( * )*  The vue integration bundle [more info](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome)
2. *( ** )* Only needed for free icons, if you own Pro *and followed the instructions [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers)*, they are are included in pro already.
3. *( *** )* As of writing, the duotone icons are not completely integrated yet, beware of errors.

**Then lets add this to our vuetify configuration:**

> I assume here that you use vuejs with javascript *(not typescript)* and that you've installed vuetify through `vue add vuetify`. The `vuetify.js` file should reside inside the `plugins` folder in your `src` folder. [Your milage may vary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/your-mileage-may-vary).

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' // Core SVG
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome' // Integration
// ... there should be more here, but see next part below ...

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon) // add it to vue
Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'faSvg', // The bees knees, what most people are looking for.
  },
});
```

Ok, now that we've added the main components of FontAwesome 5, let's use treeshaking to instruct which icons we'd like to use for our project. I will only use two icons as examples: `fa-plus` and `fa-user-circle`, and I will add them for three of the Font Awesome Pro 5 packages we installed *(Light, Regular and Duotone)* and then I will add some others (bars and user) for the solid, to see how this can be done in both ways at the same time.

So back to our `vuetify.js` file, we replace

```js
// ... there should be more here, but see next part below ...
```

with the following (note camelcase):

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js
// ...
import { 
    faBars,
    faUser
} from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons'
import {
    faPlus as farPlus,
    faUserCircle as farUserCircle
} from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons'
import {
    faPlus as falPlus,
    faUserCircle as falUserCircle
} from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons'
import {
    faPlus as fadPlus,
    faUserCircle as fadUserCircle
} from '@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons'
// ...
```

> Quick note: If you still would like to add the entire library of these, you can do that by importing like so: `import { far } from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons'` *(for regular)* and so on.

As you can see, we've now added fa-plus and fa-user-circle to our project. From here, we need to add them to the `library` we imported into the `vuetify.js` config. *(don't sweat, the whole file can be seen below in the code snippet.)*:

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js
// ...
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
library.add(
    faBars, faUser,
    farPlus, falPlus, fadPlus, 
    farUserCircle, falUserCircle, fadUserCircle
)
/// ...
```

Now that we've added them to the library, we need to hand them over to vuetify. Vuetify has some *special* icons that they use for things like the `<v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>` *(hamburger menu)*. We can customize these, and add our own to the mix (if we'd like). I do this by defining a constant and add all the icons I need in there, like so:

```js
const CUSTOM_ICONS = {
    add: { // custom icon I want to use
        component: FontAwesomeIcon,
        props: {
            icon: ['fad', 'plus']
        }
    },
    menu: { // used for the nav-icon by vuetify
        component: FontAwesomeIcon,
        props: {
            icon: ['fas', 'user']
        }
    }
}
```

and then we add this constant to the config like so:

```js
export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'faSvg',
    values: CUSTOM_ICONS,
  },
});
```

> You could also add them directly into the `values` variable, but I find it more readable to do it through a constant.

#### Now we can use these in templates, appends or prepends:

```html
<template>
    <v-app>
        <!-- reference the whole path -->
        <v-icon>$vuetify.icons.add</v-icon>
        <!-- but this is easier -->
        <v-icon>$add</v-icon>
        <v-select
            :items="direction"
            label="Select direction"
            menu-props="auto"
            prepend-icon="$unfold" <!-- short version -->
            append-icon="$vuetify.icon.unfold" <!-- long version -->
            >
        </v-select>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

### Finally, here is the complete example:

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' // Core SVG
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome' // Integration
import { 
    faBars,
    faUser
} from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons'
import {
    faPlus as farPlus,
    faUserCircle as farUserCircle
} from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons'
import {
    faPlus as falPlus,
    faUserCircle as falUserCircle
} from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons'
import {
    faPlus as fadPlus,
    faUserCircle as fadUserCircle
} from '@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons'

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
library.add(
    faBars, faUser,
    farPlus, falPlus, fadPlus, 
    farUserCircle, falUserCircle, fadUserCircle
)
const CUSTOM_ICONS = {
    add: { // custom icon I want to use
        component: FontAwesomeIcon,
        props: {
            icon: ['fad', 'plus']
        }
    },
    menu: { // used for the nav-icon by vuetify
        component: FontAwesomeIcon,
        props: {
            icon: ['fas', 'user']
        }
    }
}

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'faSvg',
    values: CUSTOM_ICONS,
  },
});
```

```html
<template>
    <v-app>
        <!-- reference the whole path -->
        <v-icon>$vuetify.icons.add</v-icon>
        <!-- but this is easier -->
        <v-icon>$add</v-icon>
        <v-select
            :items="direction"
            label="Select direction"
            menu-props="auto"
            prepend-icon="$unfold" <!-- short version -->
            append-icon="$vuetify.icon.unfold" <!-- long version -->
            >
        </v-select>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

### Suggestion separate files for better reading

We can separate the fontAwesome logic to another file:

So we have 2 files:

- the `fontAwesome.js` where you do all the logic belonging to fontAwesome
- the `vuetify.js` you will import the Icons from `fontAwesome.js`

```js
// src/plugins/fontAwesome.js
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' // Core SVG
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome' // Integration
import { 
    faBars,
    faUser
} from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons'
import {
    faPlus as farPlus,
    faUserCircle as farUserCircle
} from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons'
import {
    faPlus as falPlus,
    faUserCircle as falUserCircle
} from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons'
import {
    faPlus as fadPlus,
    faUserCircle as fadUserCircle
} from '@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons'

library.add(
    faBars, faUser,
    farPlus, falPlus, fadPlus, 
    farUserCircle, falUserCircle, fadUserCircle
)
const CUSTOM_ICONS = {
    add: { // custom icon I want to use
        component: FontAwesomeIcon,
        props: {
            icon: ['fad', 'plus']
        }
    },
    menu: { // used for the nav-icon by vuetify
        component: FontAwesomeIcon,
        props: {
            icon: ['fas', 'user']
        }
    }
}

export { CUSTOM_ICONS }
```

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import { CUSTOM_ICONS } from "./fontAwesome"

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'faSvg',
    values: CUSTOM_ICONS
  },
});
```

```html
<template>
    <v-app>
        <!-- reference the whole path -->
        <v-icon>$vuetify.icons.add</v-icon>
        <!-- but this is easier -->
        <v-icon>$add</v-icon>
        <v-select
            :items="direction"
            label="Select direction"
            menu-props="auto"
            prepend-icon="$unfold" <!-- short version -->
            append-icon="$vuetify.icon.unfold" <!-- long version -->
            >
        </v-select>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

#### Further reading:

- [Why use Font Awesome with library as a concept?](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#why-use-the-concept-of-a-library)
- [Vuetify: how to install Font Awesome 5](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons#install-font-awesome-5-icons)
- [Using Font Awesome with VueJS](https://vuejsexamples.com/font-awesome-5-vue-component/)

Comment: You deserve more upvotes. Most clean solution. Maybe a suggestion I put the logic of the fontawesome in a separte file called `fontAwesome.js` that I then import in `vuetify.js`

Comment: That is a great suggestion, and also cleaner than mine. If you'd like, you can update this answer to reflect your suggestion. :D

Comment: Updated. Also you don't need to that anymore to `Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)`

Comment: @Stevenwhy don't you need to call Vue.component('font-awesome-icon'... anymore? It is still listed on the vue-fontawesome github page under their instructions

Comment: Unfortunately your solution is completely wrong. You're doing all the imports from SVG icons then at the end you're using font icons. You can verify that by inspecting the icon on the page.

Comment: Not sure what you did on your side to arrive at those results you mention @ahmadx87, but it works on my side. Maybe you forgot to include `iconfont: 'faSvg',` ?

Comment: The two files solution seems to be missing something: " Vue warning: "Unknown custom element: <font-awesome-icon> - did you register the component correctly? "

Comment: You need to make sure you register the component with Vue. Like this `Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)` - the name `font-awesome-icon` is just a name, you could name it `bacon` if you'd like.

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks! Also @ahmadx87, it's probably not a good idea to come to the conclusion that someone's answer is "completely wrong" and not that maybe you have done something incorrent

Comment: Does this include the icons that vuetify wants to use from faSvg by default? Seems like those have to be specified and imported, but I can't find a full list of what they are...

Comment: I have followed this guide using the free version. I imported from free-solid-svg-icons and added them to my library, but when I try to use v-con like this: `<v-icon>far fa-search</v-icon>` nothing is visible. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 19):

### For a Nuxt/Vuetify Project:

Complementing the above answer, you can also set it up in the Vuetify configuration file, that is created during the project installation ( ***"plugins/vuetify.js"*** ),  adding the "iconfont" prop:

```js
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
 iconfont: 'fa'
})
```

Now, use with the icon component like this:

```html
<v-icon>fab fa-vuejs</v-icon>
```

Comment: A more complete and updated answer can now be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58261449/4301060).

Answer (score 9):

A simple solution is posted under framework options in Vuetify: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons

Install icons library using NPM or yarn:

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free -D
```

### Config - For a simple vue project

Add this to your main.js

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
 iconfont: 'fa'
})
```

### Config - For a nuxt + vuetify project

Create a js file(eg icons.js) under plugins

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'fa'
})
```

Add this to your plugins in nuxt.config.js

```
{ src: '~/plugins/icons.js', ssr:false }
```

### Usage

Now you can access font awesome icons using v-icon or append/prepend in component like:

```
<v-slider
v-model="energy"
color="red"
label="Energy"
min="1"
max="100"
thumb-label="always"
prepend-icon="fa-burn"
></v-slider>
```

Answer (score 1):

import font-awesome in src/main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

then define iconfont in src/plugins/vuetify.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'fa4' // 'md' || 'mdi' || 'fa' || 'fa4'
})
```