# FontAwesome Regular Vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, font-awesome, vuetify.js, font-awesome-5

Does anybody have a full mapping of icons for Font Awesome 5 Regular (Pro) icons to use it in vuetify.js? I could not find it yet. It has to be in this format:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

const MY_ICONS = {
  'complete': '',
  'cancel': '',
  'close': '',
  'delete': '', // delete (e.g. v-chip close)
  'clear': '',
  'success': '',
  'info': '',
  'warning': '',
  'error': '',
  'prev': '',
  'next': '',
  'checkboxOn': '',
  'checkboxOff': '',
  'checkboxIndeterminate': '',
  'delimiter': '', // for carousel
  'sort': '',
  'expand': '',
  'menu': '',
  'subgroup': '',
  'dropdown': '',
  'radioOn': '',
  'radioOff': '',
  'edit': ''
}

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  icons: MY_ICONS
})
```

Ref: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons#using-custom-icons

Without this mapping it try to use the Solid (fas) icons.

Thank you.

Comment: You could try the [vue-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome) packages?

Comment: Hi I use the package. Still in vuetify it uses normally "fas" and not "far".

Comment: If you look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58261449/4301060 you can see how it is done :)