# Fontawesome icons is not working on vuejs, vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, stylus, font-awesome-5

Setting up vuetify by clicking yes for fontawesome 5 trying to add fas fa-*** it's not works because in main.js the import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'; is not added so do it manually by adding it and install it by

for linux user:

```
sudo npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome @mdi/font
```

for windows user:

```
npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome @mdi/font
```

now you can implement the icons from fontawesome!

Comment: Yes you need to manually add css reference in main.js, checkout this https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons#install-font-awesome-5-icons

Comment: See this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58261449/4301060