How can I get FontAwesome icons to display in Vuetify checkboxes?
I'm new to Vue. I'm migrating a Vue app from BootstrapVue to Vuetify. The app already uses FontAwesome5, although it imports specific icons by name. I've managed to get icons to display, including the faCheckSquare icon. However, when I replace <b-form-checkbox> with <v-checkbox>, the <i> element is empty, so no checkbox displays.
What step am I missing to get the checkbox to render?
Here's my setup:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { aliases, fa } from 'vuetify/iconsets/fa'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import App from './App.vue'

import {
  faSquare
} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import {
  faCheck,
  faCheckSquare
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(
  faCheck,
  faCheckSquare,
  faSquare
)

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'light'
  },
  icons: {
    defaultSet: 'fa',
    aliases,
    sets: {
      fa
    }
  }
})

app.use(vuetify)

...and then this template is in a separate file—I've added a <font-awesome-icon> tag just to show that the relevant icon is, in fact, imported and loaded.
<template>
  <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'check-square']" />
  <v-checkbox value="foo" label="Foo"></v-checkbox>
</template>

What I see rendered in the web inspector is this. The icon's <svg> loads fine, but the checkbox element should also have an <svg> element inside its <i> element (apologies for all the boilerplate):
<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-square-check" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="square-check" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
  <path [...]></path>
</svg>
<div class="v-input [...] v-checkbox v-checkbox">
  <div class="v-input__control">
    <div class="v-selection-control v-selection-control--density-default v-checkbox-btn v-checkbox-btn">
      <div class="v-selection-control__wrapper">
        <div class="v-selection-control__input">
          <i class="far fa-square v-icon notranslate v-theme--light v-icon--size-default" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <input id="checkbox-5" aria-label="Foo" type="checkbox" aria-describedby="checkbox-5-messages" value="true">
        </div>
      </div>
      <label class="v-label v-label--clickable" for="checkbox-5">Foo</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="v-input__details">
    <div role="alert" aria-live="polite" id="checkbox-5-messages"></div>
  </div>
</div>

Although invisible, the checkbox "works"—i.e., it switches from <i class="far fa-square"> to <i class="fas fa-check-square"> when I click on the blank space where the icon should render.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030435/fontawesome-with-vuetify-how-to-include-font-awesome-icons-within-the-v-icon-c/58261449#58261449
